# Magento 2.1.2 admin Store configuration page the error has been processing your request

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In admin when I go to Store > Configuration the following error is showing..

---

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 59
```

Comment: Have u  using  custom module/

Comment: No,But i install some extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that some `id` attribute is not defined in `system.xml` in one of your installed extensions.

`system.xml` file has `<section>` `<group>` and `<field>` tags which requires id attribute for each.

Can you please check all system.xml files if they have id attribute defined for each of the above tags. If some is missing add it, clear your cache and then reload the page.

Edit: `<tab>` also needs to be defined with id attribute if some section use custom tab id.

```
<tab id="iwd" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
    <label>IWD OPC</label>
</tab>
```

Comment: basically i when i disable the extension iwd_opc its working fine.... So, i check the system.xml of module iwd_opc it have ids of the [link]<section>. <group> and <field>

Comment: Then can you check `acl.xml` and `<resource>` tags for id attribute?

Comment: acl.xml of this module is not exists ..

Comment: do you have empty config.xml file in your etc dir? I am not sure which version you are using? If you have empty config.xml file then remove it and try again.

Comment: i am using Magento ver. 2.1.2 i rename the config.xml and enable the module ..but still issue is not resolve the file structure are https://screenshot.net/57332hq   and config file is in https://screenshot.net/0922pc0

Comment: What version of iwd_opc are you using? where I can see it and what files are under etc dir?

Comment: the version of iwd_opc is 1.0.2 fiel under etc are https://screenshot.net/0922pc0

Comment: Can you add tab definition in `system.xml` inside `<system>` node like this:

    <tab id="iwd" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>IWD OPC</label>
        </tab>

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/iwd-opc.html   that module i am using...may be the resign is that its supposted Community 2.0 but i ma using 2.1.2 ????

Comment: I don't know I didn't install the extension, just browse the code now but I didn't see creating the tab before sections. See my updated answer with `<tab>` node